# PowerShell Set-ADGroup replace member multiple domains (FSP)

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to set the membership of a group using Set-ADGroup with the -Replace parameter. I tried with

```
$adUsers = @()
$adUsers += Get-ADUser -Server domain1.corp.com -Identity user1
$adUsers += Get-ADUser -Server domain2.corp.com -Identity user2

$adUsers = $adUsers | select-object -expandproperty distinguishedname

Set-ADGroup -Server domain3.corp.com -Identity mygroup -Replace @{Member=$adUsers}
```

but that fails with

```
The specified account does not exist.
```

If you looked at my previous attempt you might have noted that my user objects come from two different doamins while my group comes from a third one.

So to test my code, I simplified my setup and tried with users coming from the same domain as the one where the group was located in

```
$adUsers = @()
$adUsers += Get-ADUser -Server domain3.corp.com -Identity user4
$adUsers += Get-ADUser -Server domain3.corp.com -Identity user5

$adUsers = $adUsers | select-object -expandproperty distinguishedname

Set-ADGroup -Server domain3.corp.com -Identity mygroup -Replace @{Member=$adUsers}
```

This works.

So I figured the AD module might not be liking FSPs.

But then I ran the following code:

```
$adUsers = @()
$adUsers += Get-ADUser -Server domain1.corp.com -Identity user1
$adUsers += Get-ADUser -Server domain2.corp.com -Identity user2

Add-ADGroupMember -Server domain3.corp.com -Identity mygroup -Members $adUsers
```

And this works. So it seems working with FSPs is certainly possible in the AD module.

But why is it not working for Set-ADGroup?

Should I be using something different from the distinguished name? I tried with the string representation of the SID, but that seems to be even worse (An internal error occured).

I am aware that I could use a combination of Remove-ADGroupMember and Add-ADGroupMember to make my code work but that seems inefficient as I would have to figure out first which users to remove. Replacing the member list with the correct entries seems more performant.

**Update** After some more testing I discovered that using the FSP in combination with Set-ADGroup works. So I can use 'CN=S-1-5-21-xxx-yyy-zzz-rid,CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=DOMAIN3,DC=CORP,DC=com'. Of course that implies the FSP object exists already in DOMAIN3. Because if it does not and I fake the distinguishedname, the method logically just returns

```
Set-ADGroup: An internal error occurred.
```

Now I am wondering if `Set-ADGroup -replace` method can only work with existing objects while `Add-ADGroupMember` can also create (FSP) objects.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the way the data needs to be formatted. You can use a users SID but it needs to be in the format `<SID=S-1-5-21-xxx-yyy-zzz-rid>`. This way FSPs are also automatically created when necessary

So my code ended up being something like:

```
[string[]]$sids= @()
$sids+= Get-ADUser -Server domain1.corp.com -Identity user1 -Properties @('SID') | ForEach-Object { '<SID=' + $_.SID + '>'}
$sids+= Get-ADUser -Server domain2.corp.com -Identity user2 -Properties @('SID') | ForEach-Object { '<SID=' + $_.SID + '>'}

Set-ADGroup -Server domain3.corp.com -Identity mygroup -Replace @{Member=$sids}
```